# Problem to display hidden element loaded with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I'm loading an element on a page with ajax and jQuery for a personal project. But it's impossible to display some element in a very specific situation after they're append to the DOM.

Some html loads with ajax need to be displayed when the user click on another element loaded with ajax.

Example:

```
<!-- Element load with ajax and append to DOM -->

<div class="block1">
    <p>You have clicked</p>
</div>
<div class="block2">
    <p>Some Text</p>
</div>
```

I have `.block1` which is set to `display: none;` in CSS, and I want that after a click on `.block2` the CSS becomes `display: flex` for `.block1`.

So I have made this function with jQuery:

```
$(".block2").click(function () {

    if ($(".block1").css("display") === "none") {
        $(".block1").css("display", "flex");
    } else {
       $(".block1").css("display", "none");
    }

});
```

My trouble is that:

- The function work fine when `.block1`is set to `display: flex` by default (one click on `.block2` makes disappear `.block1`, the next click makes appear `.block1`).
- This doesn't work when `.block1` is set by default on `display: none`. But the function is correctly detect (I had set some `console.log()` message, and the CSS are updated too).

For information:

- The CSS are initialized in a stylesheet.

So my question is:

Why this isn't working when the CSS is by default `display: none;`, and work perfectly when the CSS is by default `display: flex;`. And how I can fix that?

Comment: First, I think you got some thing mixed up a little. You say `one click on .block1 makes disappear .block2` but It's `.block2` that has the click event.

Comment: Also if you look at this demo, what is not working for you ? https://jsfiddle.net/wt4r1n2L/

Comment: Yes, I have mixed up. I'm editing the error.

Comment: I have test the demo, and she works fine. I suppose that the problem is that the HTML elements are loaded with Ajax and that setting css to `display: none` cause a problem with the HTML DOM.

Answer (score 1):

replace $(".block2").click b

```
$(document).on('click', '.block2', function(){

     if ($(".block1").css("display") === "none") {
        $(".block1").css("display", "flex");
     } else {
         $(".block1").css("display", "none");
    }

  }
)
```

Comment: Could you please explain why ? This is not obvious to me, and perhaps to other users... https://stackoverflow.com/q/9122078/1207019

Comment: I myself had this problem. it is due to the fact that when we use click this only for the elements already present in the DOM at the time of the loading of the page. But if we add other elements by ajax or javascript simply they are not supported.
But with $ (container) .on ('click', 'selector', handler) all current or future elements are supported. Thank you !!!